# HTML Image Link not working properly in android phonegap app

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I am developing a FM Radio streaming app. When user presses in toggle button the streaming should stop when clicked again it should start.

streaming works fine but the portion where user needs to touch is not exactly coming on top of that toggle icon. Its coming slightly some where on the top portion of the icon. The portion I have circled and shown in picture.

How to create Image button with simple css and html for this case

```
<a href="#"  style="position:fixed;top: 1%;left: 5%;" onclick="toggleAudio('http://kantipur-stream.softnep.com:7248');">
<img src="images/toggle.png">
</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a touchststart, or touchend, event instead of click events, as they normally (except in VERY recent mobile Chrome browsers) have a delay. Also, I'd get rid of the link. Just add the event handler to the image itself.